# Meta Tags in Body; HTML malformed

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Facebook recently stopped crawling our featured image for our posts. It used to work fine, though. When using Facebook's debugger tool, it gives us this message:

"Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable."

Can you please help us determine the error. Here's a sample link: http://www.cmfr-phil.org/2014/12/23/highlighting-a-policy-need/

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that one of the many `iframes` is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue: the facebook scraper doesn't recognize  self closing tags placed in my  page section.

To let the scraper scrape correctly my page i had to replace all the  self-closing tag (i have an XHTML doctype) with  closing tag format.

Try this and see if it works for your page